# How can we put an integer variable into a task string?

Tags: system-verilog

Indeed I have a task to read registers:

```
task read_reg(bit[31:0] reg_addr,bit [0:31] rd_beat...);
```

The first input parameters is the address of the register that is 32-bit, as you can see. The register addresses are defined through parameters:

```
parameter int REG_0 = 32'h80440050; //R
```

So when you call the task to read a register, you can pass over the parameter to the task:

```
read_reg(REG_0,….);
```

to read e.g. REG_0.

Now, this is the call of the task that I would like to parametrize more, so I don't want to hardcode the parameter name REG_0 into it but I would like to handle it partly through another variable:

```
bit [1:0] num=0;
```

and then instead of hardcoding REG_0 when calling the task, I would like to use the variable "num" for it, so something like:

```
read_reg(REG_$num$,...)
```

just I don't know how to handle over the value of num (which is 0 in the above example) into the call of the task.

I hope I managed to give a clearer description now and that someone has an idea how to do it.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! It is very hard to follow your question. Could you try to write the question clearer and highlight your code so people could better help you.

Comment: OK, sorry that my explanation was not clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to form an identifier name from a variable. You want an array. You can do

```
parameter int REG[4]  = {32'h80440050, //R
                         32'h80450050,
                        ...};
read_reg(REG[num],...)
```

or you could create an associative array

```
int REG[string] = '{"REG_0":REG_0,"REG_1":REG_1,...};
read_reg(REG[$sformatf("REG_%0d",num)],...);
```